# Mimicking functionality of built-in types

Tags: python

I am curious if there is a way to mimic the same kind of functionality as built-in types with custom classes. The best way to explain what I am looking for is with an example.

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, val):
        self._returnVal = val

myObject = MyClass('test')
print myObject
```

Rather than the above code returning:

```
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x023861F0>
```

Is there a way to get it so when we call on the object it automatically returns self._returnVal, but also still allows us to call the methods that exist on myObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override the [`__repr__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) method:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._returnVal = val
    def __repr__(self):
        return self._returnVal
```

Now if I instantiate the class I get:

```
>>> myObject = MyClass('test')
>>> print myObject
test
```

Comment: That is great. Thanks! I had been wondering what __repr__ was for.